# Java JNA Linkedlist declaration

Tags: java, c++, struct, linked-list, jna

I need to access native C++ code .dll from Java application. native int function works well, but for Linkedlist Struct I cannot find any reference on the Internet how to declare the java interface

this C++ code

```
struct usb_relay_device_info
{
    unsigned char *serial_number;
    char *device_path;
    usb_relay_device_type type;
    usb_relay_device_info* next;
};

int EXPORT_API usb_relay_init(void);
struct usb_relay_device_info EXPORT_API * usb_relay_device_enumerate(void);
int EXPORT_API  usb_relay_device_open(struct usb_relay_device_info* device_info);
```

This is the java part

```
public interface JNI extends Library {
JNI INSTANCE = (JNI) Native.loadLibrary("usb", JNI.class);

public static class usb_relay_device_info extends Structure {
    public static class DeviceInfo extends usb_relay_device_info implements Structure.ByValue {
    }

    public byte[] serial_number = new byte[1024];
    public String device_path;
    public int type;
}


int usb_relay_init();
usb_relay_device_info.DeviceInfo usb_relay_device_enumerate();
int usb_relay_device_open(usb_relay_device_info.DeviceInfo deviceInfo);
```

}

I already created just the struct at the java code (NOT the Linkedlist Struct). So when I call the function the values are not showing up because it supposed to be a list (linkedlist in C++)

Comment: Why are there four elements in the structure and only 3 in your mapping? You've left out `next`.  Also the `char *serial_number` and other args implies a pointer to a native-mapped memory area, not a fixed width byte array.   Where did the 1024 come from?

Comment: Yes it is still missing, because the next variable is linkedlist in c++, how to declare it in Java? I was read reference from other site that unsigned char in c++ is byte array in Java. Ok so better the serial_number should change to String? The 1024 just random guessing haha.

Comment: Random guessing is rarely helpful in programming.  :). Find how the API describes that field, `char *` is most likely a null terminated string, so a `String` in Java.

Comment: As for the Next field a `Pointer` will always work but requires manually dealing with the pointer to iterate the linked list.  a `usb_relay_device_info.ByReference` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I cannot find any reference on the Internet how to declare the java interface" but there are plenty of references, including JNA's [Overview](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.5.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description), linked to the main project page.

There you will find that `char *` is a C String and should be mapped to Java's `String`.

The `usb_relay_device_type` mapping has to be referenced in the API that you're mapping.  In this case it is an `enum` type, which is an integer, so `int` is probably appropriate here. (There are cases where it can be a smaller integer value like `short` or `byte` but those are rare.)

As for the pointer to the next device, that is also referenced on the overview page under `struct*`.  The link (or explicitly) links to `Structure.ByReference`. That may not be obvious, but the [JNA FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure), also linked on the main JNA project page, amplifies.   If it's still not clear, here's a summary:

- By default, Structures listed as fields inside a Structure are treated "By Value", that is, the full structure and its fields are inserted in line.  To get this behavior you can simply declare the structure name.
- If you want the opposite behavior (By Reference) then you must explicitly state that, and JNA will map a pointer to the structure elsewhere.   This is the case you have, and the correct structure mapping is `usb_relay_device_info.ByReference`.   (You'll also need to change the structure declaration to implement ByReference -- the JNA overview, linked above, has an example of this.)
- When used in function arguments, such as `usb_relay_device_open()`, the opposite is true: the "By Reference" is the default, and you only need to explicity specify "By Value" if that's relevant.  In this case, it's not -- the native declaration includes the pointer: (`usb_relay_device_info*`) so you want the ByReference behavior.  You can just put `usb_relay_device_info device_info` there and the ByReference will be implicit.  Or, if you prefer (it's not needed) you could do `usb_relay_device_info.ByReference device_info` and it would just be redundant.

So in summary your structure mapping should be:

```
class usb_relay_device_info extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends usb_relay_device_info implements Structure.ByReference { }

    public String serial_number;
    public String device_path;
    public int type;
    public usb_relay_device_info.ByReference next;
};
```

You'll need to add the FieldOrder, preferably using an annotation.